# Othello Minimax Algorithm not working

Tags: c, algorithm, minimax

I am trying to make a minimax algorithm, but my function does not return the correct position. It returns the deepest node. I would like it to return the best possible move. Here is my code:

```
pos minimax(game* g, strategy_config sc)
{
    int points = 0;
    sc.minimax_config.heuristic(g, sc.minimax_config.hc);
    pos p, p2;
    int search_depth = sc.minimax_config.ply;
    for (p.r = 0; p.r < g->b->nrows; p.r++) 
    {
        for (p.c = 0; p.c < g->b->ncols; p.c++) 
        {
            game* copy = g;
            apply_move(copy, p);
            if (sc.minimax_config.heuristic(copy, sc.minimax_config.hc) 
                > points && sc.minimax_config.ply > 0)
            {
                if (sc.minimax_config.ply == search_depth) 
                {
                    p2 = p;
                }
                sc.minimax_config.ply = sc.minimax_config.ply - 1;
                minimax(copy, sc);
            }
        }
    }
    return p2;
}
```

And here are the relevant structs:

```
struct edge_corner_weight {
    unsigned int edge_weight;
    unsigned int corner_weight;
};

union heuristic_config {
    unsigned int edge_weight;
    struct edge_corner_weight edge_corner_weight;
};

typedef union heuristic_config heuristic_config;

struct minimax_config {
    int (*heuristic)(game*, heuristic_config);
    heuristic_config hc;
    unsigned int ply;
};

typedef struct minimax_config minimax_config;

union strategy_config {
    minimax_config minimax_config;
};
```

Comment: The posted code does not compile (and it is not a MVSE)  where are the definitions for: `game`, `pos`.  The code is missing the statement: `typedef union strategy_config strategy_config;`.  Where is the definition for `apply_move()`, `minimax()`.  What are you trying to do with this code: `union strategy_config
{
    minimax_config minimax_config;
};`?

Comment: this statement: `if (sc.minimax_config.heuristic(copy, sc.minimax_config.hc)
                > points && sc.minimax_config.ply > 0)` is checking that the returned value from sc.minimax_config.heuristic() to be greater than zero.  so why the variable `points`?  just compare to 0

Comment: exactly which part of the posted code is producing the incorrect value?

Comment: Any modification of `copy` modifies `g` since it is a pointer to the same data.